# MATLAB: How to include mean and minimum in time calculator program

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How can I get the mean(average) of my stimulation time instead of listing all the 100 stimulation time for manual calculation?

```
           function [time] = Babtime(n)
           N = 100;
           t = zeros(N,1);
           for k = 1:N
           tic;
           Bab(n);
           Stimulationtime=toc
```

Also how can I get the minimum stimulation time without me manually checking for the minimum out of 1000 output time for the code below

```
               function [time] = Haldtime(n)
               N = 1000;
               t = zeros(N,1);
               for k = 1:N
               tic;
               Hald(n);
               Stimulationtime=toc
```

Thank you

Comment: Just as a side note, but I think your functions should return `Stimulationtime` instead of `time`which is not defined.

Comment: @MatthiasW return time instead of Stimulationtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the toc values in an array, and then use min.  For your code, you already appear to have created the array to store the time values (the array t):

```
function [time] = Haldtime(n)
N = 1000;
t = zeros(N,1);
for k = 1:N
    tic;
    Hald(n);
    t(k)=toc;
end
disp(min(t));
time=min(t);
```

Of course, if you want the average (which is far more useful) then replace min with mean

Answer (score 0):

To make it more handy, letting you use any function with any number of input arguments and with variable number of run cycles, you can modify your timer function to the following:

```
function [times, t_min, t_mean] = myTimer(funcH, sampling, varargin)
times = zeros(sampling, 1);
for ii = 1:sampling
    tic;
    funcH(varargin{:});
    times(ii) = toc;
end
t_min = min(times);
t_mean = mean(times);
```

Then you can simply use this function to calculate run time of different functions. For your examples it will be:

```
[~, tmin, tavg] = myTimer(@Bab, 100, n);
```

or

```
[T, tmin, tavg] = myTimer(@Hald, 1000, n);
```

Note that in the second example all of the run times are saved in `T`, so later you can calculate different statistics besides min and mean.

It might be also useful to take a look at [`profile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html).